# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError issue while running a scala code for a UDF

Tags: scala, hive, ide, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write a UDF in scala in order to get all the months between two dates passed. This is what i have written.

```
package com.company.datediff

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF
import java.time._

class hive_udf extends UDF {
  def evaluate(date1: String, date2: String): String = {
     val s1 = LocalDate.parse(date1)
     val s2=  LocalDate.parse(date2)
     val p = Period.between(s1, s2)
     val l=p.getMonths()
     val min1= s1.getMonthValue()
     val max1= s2.getMonthValue()
     var arr1=""
     for (i <- min1 to max1){
         arr1=arr1.concat(","+ i)    
     }
     /*var i=min1
     while (i<= max1){
       arr1=arr1.concat(","+ i)
       }*/
     return arr1 
     }
}
```

---

When running this code without for loop, code runs perfectly fine. After inclusion of for loop, I am getting `'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'` and

> Execution Error, return code -101 from
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask. scala/Function1'

---

PFB the details of full error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Registry.registerToSessionRegistry(Registry.java:518)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Registry.registerPermanentFunction(Registry.java:207)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.registerPermanentFunction(FunctionRegistry.java:1536)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask.createPermanentFunction(FunctionTask.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask.execute(FunctionTask.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1748)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1494)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1291)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:380)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:740)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:685)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function1
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 26 more
FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask. scala/Function1
```

---

I have a limited exposure to java or Scala. Not sure where I am going wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some of the data you're working on?

Comment: Hi..I am trying to run this UDF in Hive like this: select diff("2016-06-01","2016-10-31"); The final output I am expecting looks like this: ,6,7,8,9,10. Code is working if I comment out the for loop. I am pretty sure that the problem is with the for loop. Thanks in advance.

Comment: works perfectly for me.. post how you define the UDF for spark and how you call it

Comment: Here is how i am calling it:
ADD JAR /aetnas98/hadoopappsqa/Vivek/hiveudftest.jar;

Comment: Here is how i am calling it:
ADD JAR /aetnas98/hadoopappsqa/Vivek/hiveudftest.jar;
CREATE FUNCTION diff as 'com.aetna.datediff.hive_udf';
select diff("2016-06-01","2016-10-31");

Also, i would like to add here that i searched online and some places it suggests that maybe i need to add some dependencies or something. Some version compatibility is not there. Something of that sort. Thanks

Comment: I added the UDF using `spark.udf.register("evaluate",(s1:String,s2:String) => evaluate(s1,s2))` and it worked. Try that

Comment: Have you made these changes in .scala file?

Comment: Made what changes? I ran it all in the shell

Comment: Okay..I'll try that..I wrote this code in scala IDE, made a jar, then ran from Hive CLI the way I mentioned above. Thanks.. i'll keep you posted

Comment: Hi.. can you please elaborate how are you running the code.. i am looging in to Hive CLI and running it.. "spark.udf.register("evaluate",(s1:String,s2:String) => evaluate(s1,s2))" do i need to run this command from my edge node shell prompt or what? Finally i intend to use this UDF in hive.. Please suggest

Comment: Also, can you specify whether you are running my exact same code or made any changes? like are you making an object for this or running the code as it is

Comment: I was working on Hive from Spark, not as a standalone. My bad..

Comment: Okay.. Can you please check for standalone once

Comment: Not using Hive as a standalone.. sorry

Comment: No issues.. Thanks a lot